# Creating a 100K*100K (10 billion element) sparse matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, element, sparse-matrix

I have a csv file that contains 2 columns .Column 1 has the username and Column 2 the username to whom the user has replied to. There are a total of 2 million records in the file. There are around a 100K unique usernames in Column1 and Column 2. I want to create a 100K*100K matrix that will give the number of times each user has communicated with the other 99,999 users. Is it possible to create the matrix in R? Obviously the matrix will be very sparse with at least 99.98% of the matrix being zero's since there are only 2 million records out of the possible 10 billion that is merely a 0.02 percent. How do I find how many times each user has communicated with the other 99,999 users and put it in the form of a matrix?

Comment: You can reduce computation since, User1:User2 == User2:User1... That is, the number of times User1 has communicated with User2 is the same as the number of times User2 has communicated with User1. Is this true?

Comment: No I do not know how many times the users have communicated with each other. I have to find it and it will definitely not be the same that is User1:User2 != User2:User1

Comment: It would be helpful to define "reply" and "communicate", and tell us how they differ, and provide some sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sparseMatrix` from the `Matrix` package:

```
 require(Matrix)
 #this just to generate some random strings
 require(stringi)
 set.seed(1)
 #generating 100k usernames
 users<-stri_rand_strings(100000,6)
 #simulating col1 and col2
 col1<-sample(users,1000000,T)
 col2<-sample(users,1000000,T)
 #hashing to integer values through factor
 col1<-factor(col1,levels=users)
 col2<-factor(col2,levels=users)
 #creating the matrix
 mySparseMatrix<-sparseMatrix(as.numeric(col1),as.numeric(col2),x=1)
 #not a huge object
 object.size(mySparseMatrix)
 #12400720 bytes
```

In this way you create a `sparseMatrix` whose `i,j` value is one if the i-th user communicates the j-th user and 0 otherwise.

**Edit**

If you want also to show how many times the i-th user communicated with the j-th, we can ask help to the `data.table` package. Just after creating `col1` and `col2`:

```
  require(data.table)
  dt<-data.table(col1=factor(col1,levels=users),col2=factor(col2,levels=users))
  #aggregating by col1 and col2
  dt<-dt[,list(times=.N),by=list(col1,col2)]
  mySparseMatrix<-sparseMatrix(as.numeric(dt$col1),as.numeric(dt$col2),x=dt$times)
```

Comment: Thank you. If the i-th user communicates with the j-th user twice will it show 2.

Comment: You have a typo on `col2=factor(col1,levels=users)`, should be `(col2,levels...` I guess.

Comment: @nicola I am trying to read col1 and col2 from a csv file and do the factorization but I am just getting one value in the dt data frame. col1 and col2 have 2 million records.